# ID Conditional User Contact Methods Not Saving

Tags: plugins

I'm working on a plugin which adds fields to the contact methods on the user profile page. It checks to see if the user is added to the plugin database and returns 1 if he is. This works and the plugin only shows the contact fields to the users who are added by it won't let them save changes in the contact field.

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'contactmethods');

function contactmethods($user_contactmethods){
global $wpdb;
global $profileuser;
$id = $profileuser->ID;
$table  = $wpdb->prefix . "table";
$myrows = NULL;
$myrows = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id = %d LIMIT 1', $id));
    if($ba_myrows == 1){
        $user_contactmethods['option'] = 'link';
    }
    return $user_contactmethods;
}
```

Comment: plugin specific questions are off-topic here. You should ask the plugin's author.

Comment: I am the author. Wordpress won't save when I conditionally add the contact methods.

Comment: cool, then you need to edit the question because I can't understand what exactly are you asking, for example have no idea what "won't save"

Comment: I edited the description.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have `$profileuser` set up on the POST handler that's actually doing the save, so when it runs this code it's got nothing to do the test with. I'm not sure what the alternative is, though. (And, to be clear, when you say "won't let them save" you mean that it fails silently: there's no validation or error message displayed?)

Comment: I check the user id while displaying the field to show it to select users. Nothing shows up in the error log.

Comment: Right: but when you try to save the page it runs the code not in the context of the page and doesn't have `$profileuser`. Or at least that's what my experiment shows: I added code to `trigger_error()` if `$profileuser` wasn't set in a user_contactmethods handler, and I do see my error in my debug.log three times when I press 'update'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$profileuser` is only initialised by `user-edit.php` but the update is posted to `/wp-admin/profile.php` and does not get as far as user-edit before running your user_contactmethods handler in the context of the save - i.e. `$profileuser` is not available when actually running the update.

Fortunately there is another global `$user_id` that is initialised both on the contact page and in the contact update handler. Instead, try:

```
function contactmethods($user_contactmethods) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $user_id;

    $table  = $wpdb->prefix . "table";
    $myrows = NULL;
    $myrows = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id = %d LIMIT 1',
                           $user_id));

    if($ba_myrows == 1) {
        $user_contactmethods['option'] = 'link';
    }
    return $user_contactmethods;
}
```

i.e. using `$user_id` in place of your `$id` calculated from `$profileuser`.

Comment: Thanks this does work. I did try using the current user id but the problem with that was if an administrator or any other moderator was editing another users profile it would use the id of the person editing the profile. I also tried previously getting the user id from the url but that wouldn't show when the user was editing his own profile and only shows when an administrator or a moderator was editing another users profile.

Answer (score 2):

`user_contactmethods` filter gets two parameters and you are ignoring them.

Proper code should be

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'contactmethods',10,2);

function contactmethods($methods,$user){
global $wpdb;
$id = $user->ID;
$table  = $wpdb->prefix . "table";
$myrows = NULL;
$myrows = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id = %d LIMIT 1', $id));
    if($ba_myrows == 1){
        $user_contactmethods['option'] = 'link';
    }
    return $user_contactmethods;
}
```

Comment: The $user->ID doesn't have any value.

Comment: does $user have a value?

Comment: I tried to echo $user and it showed nothing.

Comment: edited, was na extra parameter in the function declaration.

Comment: Ah: I didn't know about that parameter (and [nor does the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_contactmethods) :-/ ). In hindsight I think that this a better solution than mine: this parameter is passed by `wp_update_user` which is the function that actually does the update and doesn't rely on external context and will e.g. still be correct if you have a plugin that updates users though some route other than the admin pages.

Comment: On the downside, [in comments in user.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.9.2/wp-includes/user.php#L1885) the `$user` parameter is documented as optional - but in practice I think it'll be safe to assume.

Comment: hmmm, it was strange that guessing a global variable was needed which what brought me to look at it at all, but since the web is full with tutorials that ignore that parameter I guess it is something relatively new. I have tested it to work on 3.8

Comment: :-) Agree, but I'm starting to think WordPress is riddled with globals you can't avoid using. Skimming the tags the `$user` parameter was added in 3.1.

Comment: just because wordpress is riddled with globals is not a good enough reason to let the copy and paste people to keep using bad code. Trying to make the world a better place by killing one global at a time :)

Comment: Is the $user parameter passed to the function?